# Jqgrid spring date binding exception

Tags: spring, jqgrid

OS: Windows Vista, Framework: Jqgrid (latest), Spring (latest), JQuery (latest)
I am using Jqgrid to post a form to Spring Controller to persist. When the Spring controller tries to auto bind the request parameters to domain object, it throws exception when trying to bind 'Date' data type. I am using JSon format for transfer data. The Jqgrid display the date correctly. The transfer string contains '&-quot;' characters before and after the date that causes the exception. I dont know how to remove the escape character from Jqgrid. I dont know how to intercept the string before Spring gets a chance to auto bind. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
    public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {
private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
AtOverride
public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    gen.writeString(formattedDate);
}
```

}

My controller class has initBinder method.

```
        @InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
}

Exception stack trace
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Unable to convert value &quot;2010-12-01 11:10:00&quot; from type 'java.lang.String' to type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doBind(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:820)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:359)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to set-up a tutorial on my blog if I get the time today.

My JSP file is just a simple JSP file with your typical JqGrid declaration:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jq(function() {
    // This is the grid
    jq("#grid").jqGrid({
        url:'/myapp/users',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames:['Id','Username','First Name'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'id',index:'id', width:55,editable:false,editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10},hidden:true},
            {name:'firstName',index:'firstName', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}, editrules:{required:true}},
            {name:'lastName',index:'lastName', width:80, align:"right",editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10}, editrules:{required:true}}
        ],
        postData: { 
            // Here you can post extra parameters
            // For example using JQuery you can retrieve values of other css elements
        },
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        height: 200,
        autowidth: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        pager: '#pager',
        sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        caption:"Users",
        emptyrecords: "Empty records",
        loadonce: false,
        loadComplete: function() {
            // Here you can provide extra functions after the grid is loaded completely
            // Like auto-height function
        },
        jsonReader : {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false, 
            cell: "cell",
            id: "id"
        }
    });

    // This is the pager
    jq("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
            {edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:true},
            { },
            { },
            { }, 
            { 
                sopt:['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt', 'cn', 'bw', 'ew'],
                closeOnEscape: true, 
                    multipleSearch: true, 
                    closeAfterSearch: true }
    );

    // Custom Add button on the pager
    jq("#grid").navButtonAdd('#pager',
            {   caption:"Add", 
                buttonicon:"ui-icon-plus", 
                onClickButton: addRow,
                position: "last", 
                title:"", 
                cursor: "pointer"
            } 
    );

    // Custom Edit button on the pager
    jq("#grid").navButtonAdd('#pager',
            {   caption:"Edit", 
                buttonicon:"ui-icon-pencil", 
                onClickButton: editRow,
                position: "last", 
                title:"", 
                cursor: "pointer"
            } 
    );

    // Custom Delete button on the pager
    jq("#grid").navButtonAdd('#pager',
        {   caption:"Delete", 
            buttonicon:"ui-icon-trash", 
            onClickButton: deleteRow,
            position: "last", 
            title:"", 
            cursor: "pointer"
        } 
    );


    // Toolbar Search
    jq("#grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : true, defaultSearch:"cn"});

});
```

Take note I'm using JQuery's noConflict method here. Since I have another Javascript framework that uses the **$**, I forced JQuery to use a different identifier for itself. I picked jq and here's the declaration:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

The Javascript's above can be declared on the head section of your JSP. The critical part of the JqGrid declaration is the **jsonReader** and the **datatype**. Make sure the colModel name matches your model properties.

Comment: Take note of the URL as well. That is the url that should populate your grid.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use StringTrimmerEditor's second constructor to delete those extra chars

```
StringTrimmerEditor(String charsToDelete, boolean emptyAsNull)
```

Based on the Spring docs:

> charsToDelete - a set of characters to delete, in addition to trimming an input String. Useful for deleting unwanted line breaks. E.g. "\r\n\f" will delete all new lines and line feeds in a String.

I also use the latest version of JqGrid and Spring 3, but the way I handled the parameters seems to be simpler. Here's how I did it:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/json")
public class JsonController {

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody JsonResponse getAll(
                @RequestParam("_search") String search,
                @RequestParam(value="filters", required=false) String filters,
                @RequestParam(value="datefrom", required=false) String datefrom,
                @RequestParam(value="dateto", required=false) String dateto,
                @RequestParam(value="page", required=false) String page,
                @RequestParam(value="rows", required=false) String rows,
                @RequestParam(value="sidx", required=false) String sidx,
                @RequestParam(value="sord", required=false) String sord
        ) { ... }
```

All parameters are passed as normal Strings. The **datefrom** and **dateto** are custom parameters I passed from the JqGrid. The date comes from a JQuery's DatePicker and passed via JqGrid postData:

```
postData: { 
            datefrom: function() { return jq("#datepicker_from").datepicker("getDate"); },
            dateto: function() { return jq("#datepicker_to").datepicker("getDate"); }
        },
```

**JsonResponse** is a simple POJO that I used to map the search parameters passed by a JqGrid:

```
public class JsonResponse {

/**
 * Current page of the query
 */
private String page;

/**
 * Total pages for the query
 */
private String total;

/**
 * Total number of records for the query
 */
private String records;

/**
 * An array that contains the actual data
 */
private List<MyDTO> rows;

public JsonResponse() {
}

public String getPage() {
    return page;
}

public void setPage(String page) {
    this.page = page;
}

public String getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(String total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public String getRecords() {
    return records;
}

public void setRecords(String records) {
    this.records = records;
}

public List<MyDTO> getRows() {
    return rows;
}

public void setRows(List<MyDTO> rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
}
```

}

**MyDTO** is a simple DTO object as well.

In my Spring applicationContext.xml, I just have to declare the following:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

And added the Jackson jar for converting from JSON to POJO and vice versa

To convert the String date to a real Date, I used the great Joda library. But of course, you can use JDK's standard Date.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the suggestion. I will try them out. I have one more request. Because you are also using Jqgrid/Spring, will it be possible to share sample code for the below pieces? Even though I have gone through the documentation of Jqgrid, it is not very clear what is the best way to implement it. It will be useful to look at your code and understand how you have implemented it.

Comment: 1. JSP page containing JQgrid call and all the related functions/form definition.
2. Spring Controller for search and add/modify methods. How do you do bind?
3. How do you use Jackson for serialize/de-serialize.

I know it is a bit of trouble, but it will be very useful for me, if you can provide.

Thanks in advance,
JP

Comment: I have added a couple of sample code. I hope you'll be able to follow them. Start with the JSP, then the Spring XML config, then the Controller. I'm not sure if my way is the best way but I do think it's simple enough :)

Answer (score 0):

If you notice on my JSP, I added custom buttons. The **onClickButton** calls another Javascript function. For example on the **Add** button, I have the addRow function. Here's the   function declaration:

```
function addRow() {

    // Get the currently selected row
    jq("#grid").jqGrid('editGridRow','new',
            {   url: "/myapp/users/add", 
                    editData: {
                    // Here you add extra post parameters
                },
                recreateForm: true,
                beforeShowForm: function(form) {
                    // Here you can add, disable, hide elements from the popup form
                 },
                closeAfterAdd: true,
                reloadAfterSubmit:false,
                afterSubmit : function(response, postdata) 
                { 
                    // This is a callback function that will evaluate the response sent by your Controller
                    var result = eval('(' + response.responseText + ')');
                    var errors = "";

                    if (result.success == false) {
                        // Do whatever you like if not successful
                    }  else {
                        // Do whatever you like if  successful
                    }

                    // only used for adding new records
                    var new_id = null;

                    // Then this will be returned back to the popup form
                    return [result.success, errors, new_id];
                }
            });

}
```

Take note of the url:

```
url: "/myapp/users/add"
```

This is the mapping to your Controller that handles the add request

Answer (score 0):

Now, for the Jackson serialization/deserialization, you'll be suprised how easy it is.

First, make sure you have the latest Jackson library in your classpath. Next, open your Spring xml config, and add the following:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

That's it :)

Make sure you have the latest dependency jars. I use Spring 3.0.4. There's 3.0.5 already. Also, make sure you have the latest aspectjweaver.jar. If you wanna know what's inside that mvc-annotation-driven tag, just search the web and you'll see what it contains. Basically it automatically declares an HTTPMessageConverter for JSON, and uses Jackson by default.

Comment: Thanks! a tonne Chris :) This will really help me a lot! Thanks again and this is awesome!

Comment: I also agree that the tutorial is a great idea! Many people will benefit from it for sure :)

Comment: I've posted the tutorial at http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/jqgrid-and-spring-3-mvc-integration.html

Comment: Thanks!. I was trying to find link to your blog going through your profile but you read my mind :)

Answer (score 0):

For the Controller, here's the mapping to the /myapp/users/add request:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/myapp/users")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody JsonGenericResponse addAsJson(
           @RequestParam("id") String id,
           @RequestParam("firstName") String firstName,
           @RequestParam("lastName") String lastName
    ) {

            // Validate input

            // Process data. Call a service, etc.

            // Send back a response
            // JsonGenericResponse is a custom  POJO 
            // Jackson will automatically serialize/deserialize this POJO to a JSON
            // The @ResponseBody annotation triggers this behavior

            JsonGenericResponse response = new JsonGenericResponse();
            response.setSuccess(false);
            response.setMessage("Error in server");

            return response;
    }
}
```

Here's the JsonGenericResponse:

```
public class JsonGenericResponse {

private Boolean success;
private List<String> message;

public JsonGenericResponse() {
    message = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public Boolean getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
    this.success = success;
}

public List<String> getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message.add(message);
}
```

}

It's just really a simple POJO.

In your JSP, to process the response, you use JavaScript in your JqGrid. The response will be sent back to whomever the caller (the add form in this case). Here's a sample JavaScript that will process the response:

```
                if (result.success == false) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.message.length; i++) {
                        errors +=  result.message[i] + "<br/>";
                    }
                }  else {
                    jq("#dialog").text('Entry has been edited successfully');
                    jq("#dialog").dialog( 
                            {   title: 'Success',
                                modal: true,
                                buttons: {"Ok": function()  {
                                    jq(this).dialog("close");} 
                                }
                            });
                }

                return [result.success, errors, null];
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the formatting. It's hard to format the JavaScript here that I copied directly from my JSP page.